# Dart / Flutter ffi on linux - Problem to configure CMake

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, cmake, dart-ffi

I currently need to call a C++ function in my Flutter project, for a Linux desktop application (using dart:ffi). This page https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop#first-party-library doesn't explain how to configure this kind of projects on Linux (neither for Windows).

After a few try, I'm unable to correctly link the C++ library.

The C++ Function

```cpp
#include<iostream>
extern "C" {
void do_something(const char *program_name, const char *password)
{
 //Do something with data 

}
}
```

I added the following  lines to the CMakeLists.txt :

```
add_library(my_native STATIC ../native_lib/my_native.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${BINARY_NAME} PUBLIC my_native)
```

And finally, I'm linking in Dart the following way :

```dart
// Since the CMake code was added in the executable CMakeLists.txt, it seems that it
// is supposed to be done that way, with DynamicLibrary.executable() rather than DynamicLibrary.process()
// method
final DynamicLibrary lib = DynamicLibrary.executable();
final doSomethingFuncPointer = lib.lookup<NativeFunction<do_something_signature>>("do_something");
```

It compiles fine, but at startup, the program returns the following error :

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol (/home/me/Documents/flutter/desktop_installer_framework/build/linux/debug/bundle/installer: undefined symbol: do_something)
```

I also tried with dynamic linking (marking the library as `SHARED` in CMakeLists.txt and linking it with `DynamicLibrary.open("libmy_native.so")`). Also tried  calling `DynamicLibrary.process()` and putting the CMake lines inside the second CMakeLists.txt (the one in linux/flutter). It never finds symbols. So, I think I'm missing something here.
Any help would be appreciated.
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You've shown the definition; is that also the declaration? If so (which seems likely since you have the `extern` there) you are missing the `visibilty` and `used` annotations that the page you linked to described needing for C++, which would explain why the symbol isn't in the resulting binary.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean. According to you, `visibility` and `used` annotations must be written in  what side ? Dart, C++ or CMake ?

Comment: I found what you meant. I added the `visibility` and `used` annotations, and it still cant find symbols.

Comment: Finally could do it for a shared library (by linking in dart to the absolute path of resulting dynamic library). But static linkage still doesn't work here.